# Publish Sharepoint App programatically

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-hosted-app, publishing

Is it possible to publish a SharePoint hosted App programatically via a Powersell script or a post-deploy script?

And how would this be done?

EDIT: Okay, found myself a solution:

```
$instance = Get-SPAppInstance -web {SiteCollection} | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq "SharePointApp1" }

$spappv2 = Import-SPAppPackage -Path {PathToApp} -Site {SiteCollection} -Source ObjectModel

Update-SPAppInstance –Identity $instance –App $spappv2
```

Buuuut the App is already installed and I get a `the provided app differs from another app with the same version and product id`-error...

Maybe someone knows help for this...